# Download folder from Gerrit through HTTP

Tags: git, gerrit

Can I download folder from Gerrit through HTTP without cloning the entire repository?

Comment: AFAIK not from gerrit directly. Do you have gitweb support enabled in Gerrit? This would allow to download an archive.

Comment: yes I have gitweb enabled, how can I download a folder through HTTP get with gitweb?

Answer (score 1):

There is a URL for downloading a snapshot (for example for the folder XYZ/abc.git/branch-1/Apple): https://gerrit-server:8081/gitweb?p=XYZ/abc.git;a=snapshot;h=10713acc7ccf3a0d23dbe5b2bf0bd2a1ffef4424;sf=tgz in format tar.gz
The problem with URL is that the path (branch-1/Apple in this case) gets translated to the latest SHA1 of the tree object of that path (h=10713….). By this I mean, that everything will work OK using the previous URL till a commit (change) is inserted in or under the path, then a new tree object is generated having a new SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

Click on *tree* and then on *snapshot*. The resulting URL is like this: 
https://example.com/gitweb?p=repo.git.git;a=snapshot;h=HEAD;sf=tgz

See e.g. [here](https://review.typo3.org/gitweb?p=Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git;a=tree).